# SQL Server automatic transaction log truncation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, rdbms, transaction-log

Have looked through msdn but cant find answers to these:

Any help much appreciated:

In simple recovery mode:

1. Is there any TSQL or alternative functionality that will provide a notification either written to the event logs or a message or an alert , stating that the Microsoft automatic transaction log truncation is happening i.e when a checkpoint is reached sql server truncates.
   (According to this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189085(v=sql.105).aspx)
2. Is there anyway to find out how long it takes for automatic truncation to happen /how long it takes for the transaction log to be truncated?
3. Does the SQL Server condition performance alerts happen in real time or in intervals or say 5 mins?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

No physical truncation actually occurs, the size of the file would not get smaller.

Parts of the logfile (virtual logfile/vlf) are merely flagged as 'the content is allowed to be overwritten'. If such an event exists, and I know of none, there would be no practical duration.

If you are referring to 'auto-shrink', I would highly recommend you read this post '[Auto-shrink – turn it OFF!](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/auto-shrink-turn-it-off/)' by Paul Randal.

Comment: Looks like you're answering a different question.

Comment: No, this answer was for this question. How would you interpret the regarding 'automatic transaction log truncation'?

Comment: +1, yes. FIle getting smaller is not truncation but shrinking - with a tons of problems. Truncation is merely a marker "reuse the virtual log file X in the physical file".

Comment: In fairness, transaction log shrinking isn't as problematic as data file shrinking, but if you're doing it on a regular basis, then you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks I mean in simple recovery mode - automatic truncation occurs when a checkpoint is reached or the log gets over 70 % in size - is there any way to notify the user that the automatic truncation is happening ?